# Unable to select from SYS.TABLES - Table or View does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I read that

```
USER_TABLES is tables which you own
ALL_TABLES is tables which own, and tables owner by other users, which you have been granted explicit access to
DBA_TABLES is all tables in the database
All three are views of the underlying SYS tables
```

Based on the above and mention of SYS.TABLES in the Oracle Docs, I tried to

```
 select * from SYS.TABLES;
```

but it resulted in an error that the table or view does not exist. I tried as both SYS and another username.

**Question 1:**
Is SYS.TABLES a valid table in Oracle 11g ?

**Question 2:**
If yes, is SYS.TABLES the underlying table for the view DBA_TABLES ?

**Question 3:**
If yes, what privileges do I need to select from the SYS.TABLES ?

**Question 4:**
How do I find the underlying column and the tables for a view such as DBA_TABLES ?

I have edited the question. Sorry about the confusion I caused earlier.

Comment: Do you mean `SYS.DBA_TABLES` instead of `SYS.TABLES`?  It might help to post the exact SQL statement and error message.

Comment: You say you're "trying to select from SYS.TABLES". This could be an example of [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 11g (XE, though; never mind that).

As you wonder about `SYS`-owned objects, connect as such.

```
SQL> select * from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
```

### 1.

Does `TABLES` exist? Nope.

```
SQL> desc tables;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object tables does not exist
```

But, `TAB` does:

```
SQL> desc tab;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TNAME                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 TABTYPE                                            VARCHAR2(7)
 CLUSTERID                                          NUMBER
```

### 2.

In order to find what `DBA_TABLES` really is:

```
SQL> select owner, object_type from dba_objects where object_name = 'DBA_TABLES';

OWNER                          OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------
SYS                            VIEW
PUBLIC                         SYNONYM
```

### 4.

OK, it is a view. Which query is it made of?

```
SQL> set long 20000
SQL> select text from dba_views where view_name = 'DBA_TABLES';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select u.name, o.name,
       decode(bitand(t.property,2151678048), 0, ts.name,
              decode(t.ts#, 0, null, ts.name)),
       decode(bitand(t.property, 1024), 0, null, co.name),
       decode((bitand(t.property, 512)+bitand(t.flags, 536870912)),
              0, null, co.name),
       decode(bitand(t.trigflag, 1073741824), 1073741824, 'UNUSABLE', 'VALID'),
<snip>
from sys.user$ u, sys.ts$ ts, sys.seg$ s, sys.obj$ co, sys.tab$ t, sys.obj$ o,
     sys.obj$ cx, sys.user$ cu, x$ksppcv ksppcv, x$ksppi ksppi,
     sys.deferred_stg$ ds
where o.owner# = u.user#
  and o.obj# = t.obj#
  and bitand(t.property, 1) = 0
  and bitand(o.flags, 128) = 0
  and t.bobj# = co.obj# (+)
  and t.ts# = ts.ts#
<snip>
```

(It is a quite long query so I displayed only some parts of it; now that you know how to do it, do it yourself for more info).

`TAB` is, on the other hand, quite simpler:

```
SQL> select text from dba_views where view_name = 'TAB';

TEXT
---------------------------------------------------------------
select o.name,
      decode(o.type#, 2, 'TABLE', 3, 'CLUSTER',
             4, 'VIEW', 5, 'SYNONYM'), t.tab#
  from  sys.tab$ t, sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ" o
  where o.owner# = userenv('SCHEMAID')
  and o.type# >=2
  and o.type# <=5
  and o.linkname is null
  and o.obj# = t.obj# (+)
```

You'd use the same principle for "tables" specified in the `FROM` clause, e.g.

```
SQL> select owner, object_type from dba_objects where object_name = 'TAB$';

OWNER                          OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------
SYS                            TABLE
```

So - yes, that's the end. `TAB$` is the final table, there's nothing behind.

### 3.

If connected as `SYS`, you don't need any additional privileges. `SYS` owns the database, it is *the boss*, it can do *anything*.

For other users, owner grants privileges, e.g. (still connected as `SYS`):

```
SQL> grant select on tab$ to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on x$ksppcv to scott;
grant select on x$ksppcv to scott
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views


SQL>
```

That should be it, I presume.

---

Just a note: `SYS` is, as I said, powerful. Be careful what you do. I hope you have a database to spare like I do; nothing much will happen if I screw something here, there's no important data stored in it. Don't play games on production databases.

Comment: Thank You @Littlefoot. I'll stay clear of SYS. I intend to do nothing more than few SELECT statements. Thank You once again.

Comment: @Littlefoot, at answer #4 what would it mean if you find that `sys.deferred_stg$` is missing??  see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63144502/1657465

Comment: As pmdba said as a comment to your question, you should probably contact Oracle Support. I wouldn't know why it is missing in your database, @Luis. Sorry.